# Query for Joining Multiple Associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I managed to make query with joined table. I wonder how could I **add another join table** (e.g. publication_comments), **count how many comments publication have**, **sum publication_comments_count with reviews_count** and **order in DESC** order.

I have read rails guide and many example on stackoverflow, however still need somebody to assist on syntax and how exactly should I gather all pieces in one place. Thanks.

```
@publication = Publication.all(
                          joins: :reviews,
                          select: '"publications".*, count("reviews".id) as reviews_count', 
                          group: '"publications".id',
                          order: "reviews_count DESC")
```

Comment: I suggest you to to one step at a time, ex., first retrieve all of them, then try to make the join, the count, etc. Another thing is that, if you are using `rails v >= 3` use the new syntax, don't use the `find` with `select`, `group`, `order`, etc inside it.

Comment: I use rails 3.2. Can you post an answer?!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord allows you to just supply a string to the joins method. So you can just write raw SQL join conditions:

```
Publication.select("..., COUNT(publication_comments.id) as pub_count")
 .join('JOIN reviews on (..) JOIN publication_comments')
 .group('publications.id'
```

Comment: Most of all I wonder how I sum reviews_count and pub_count in a query? Would I use sum method or just plus them(somehow) and make DESC order?

Comment: Actually to see the number of reviews you don't want to SUM them but rather COUNT them (as in my sample above) - that way you get the number of reviews, not the sum of their ID values.

Comment: In question I use count as well! However I ask how to make reviews_count + pub_count = sum? This sum I would use in order: "sum DESC"